# Difficulty in plotting 3D data, plot_wireframe python matplotlib

Tags: python

I am facing difficulty while plotting my 3d data using wireframe, please help.
It is working in plot3D but not in wireframe.

Python code is given here.

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv


file="xyz.dat"
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

with open(file,'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in data:
        if(row):
            x.append(row[0])
            y.append(row[1])
            z.append(row[2])

x = map(float,x)
y = map(float,y)
z = map(float,z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d')


#ax.plot3D(x, y, z, color = 'green') 
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color = 'green')

plt.show()
```

### data file

0 0 0

0 1 0

0 2 0

1 0 10

1 1 10

1 2 10

2 0 10

2 1 10

2 2 10

3 0 10

3 1 10

3 2 10

4 0 50

4 1 50

4 2 50

6 0 50

6 1 50

6 2 50

7 0 90

7 1 90

7 2 90

9 0 90

9 1 90

9 2 90

### end data file

Comment: Please provide the data. Note that that for wire frame the data needs to be 2d as per the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html?highlight=wireframe#wireframe-plots)

Comment: Data file is added here now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got it.

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import csv


file="xyz.txt"
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

with open(file,'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in data:
        if(row):
            x.append(row[0])
            y.append(row[1])
            z.append(row[2])

x = map(float,x)
y = map(float,y)
z = map(float,z)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = griddata((x,y),z,(X,Y),method='linear')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, color = 'green')

plt.show()
```